# enable theme in Windows GINA DLL

Tags: c++, windows-xp, gina

I made a GINA DLL to use on Windows XP using code from [micro soft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx) [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163786.aspx). I compiled the code to a DLL, but if I use it the login dialog uses Windows classic theme including the title bar, while MSGINA DLL uses the XP Luna theme. How can I enable themes on custom GINA DLL?

Answer (score 0):

The Gina is a host in `winlogon.exe`, so you don't have full control over what is happening.

Decompile the resources of `msgina.dll` and look for [manifest entries like this one](https://www.codeguru.com/cplusplus/a-simple-way-to-enable-a-windows-xp-look-and-feel-for-vc-6-0-mfc-applications/) and copy them over your DLL.